# How to parse the data from CSV FILE to arrays so it could be used for a pre-formatted Highchart

Tags: csv, highcharts

I am trying to parse the data from the CSV file and I went through the instructions in http://www.highcharts.com/docs . However, the code provided use the parsed data directly to create a new chart and I cannot understand how to apply it to my current chart. I am trying to take the strings from CSV file and use them as arrays in JavaScript to substitute the numerical arrays in the code below.

This is the graph that needs to be used:
http://jsfiddle.net/strawberry/Cyxv6/

**Data that needs to be taken from the file is the following:**

categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014']

name: 'avocado'
            ...
                data: [1600,1540,1350,1450,1600],

name: 'apples',
            ...
            data: [39000, 40000, 40500, 41000, 42000],

name: 'oranges',
            ...
            data: [8000, 5000, 4000, 4500, 3000],

name: 'bananas',
            ...
            data: [4000, 6000, 4500, 5000, 4600],

**The data from CSV file:**

year    avocado apples  oranges bananas
y2010   1600    39000   8000    4000
y2011   1540    40000   5000    6000
y2012   1350    40500   4000    4500
y2013   1450    41000   4500    5000
y2014   1600    42000   3000    4600

**The code:**

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'apples and oranges and bananas and avocado'
        },
        // subtitle: {
        //     text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        // },


        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014']
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'other',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'fruits',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],

        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'center',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            x: 0,


            title: {
                text: '<span style="font-size: 11px; color: #666; font-weight: normal" >To single out the different datasets, please click on the respective names below:</span>',
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic'
                }

            }
        },






       series: [{
                name: 'avocado',
                color: '#d6bfe3',
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [1600,1540,1350,1450,1600],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' '
                }

        }, {
            name: 'apples',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            color: '#4da90c',
            lineWidth: 3,
            type: 'spline',

            dataLabels: {
                enabled: 'True'
            },
            data: [39000, 40000, 40500, 41000, 42000],

            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            }
        },

        {
            name: 'oranges',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            color: '#f8a632',
            lineWidth: 3,
            type: 'spline',
            data: [8000, 5000, 4000, 4500, 3000],

            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            }
        },


        {
            name: 'bananas',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            color: '#939b9d',
            style: "Dash",
            lineWidth: 3,
            type: 'spline',
            dashStyle: 'longdash',
            data: [4000, 6000, 4500, 5000, 4600],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            }
        }



        ]
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you need to familiar how our parse works with our data. Then adapt parser to your data, to achive structure (like you have hardcoded). You need to also convert 'y2003' to year, by skipping first letter. (i.e by indexOf or match on string).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is exactly what I was trying to do and if I use my data with an example (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json), the data is parsed correctly, but I cannot recreate for my own code. 
My concern is how to save a row from the csv file and give a name to it so I could use it in the future (not necessarily in the graph).